# What has been added and/or changed in the 2 Gurren Lagann movies compared to TV series?

Tags: gurren-lagann

From what I heard, the 2 Gurren Lagann movies are shortened version of the TV series. Is there anything new added or modified in the movies, or are they just summaries of the TV series? If there are any additions or modifications, would you please list them out?

I am aware that the content is compressed, so it is expected that many scenes from the TV series will be shortened to squeeze 675 minutes' worth of content into 120 (Gurren-hen) + 130 (Lagann-hen) = 250 minutes of the 2 movies. I am only interested in the **new scenes** and **modifications to existing plot**. An exclusion caused by modification to existing plot also counts.

Answer (score 4):

The first movie (Gurren-hen or Childhood's End) is basically a recap of the first half of the tv series, similarly the second movie (Lagann-hen or The Lights in the Sky Are Stars) covers the second half.

There is around 20 minutes of new material in the first film and a bit more in the second film - primarily added in the final battle

The only changes in plot were that

> Makken doesn't die

&

> The Gurren Lagann evolves to an even higher stage, becoming Dai Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann which is even larger than galaxies!

There's an overall improvement in the animation quality, noticeably making battle scenes more thrilling.

[image: simon looking awesome]

also seemingly Yoko's breasts are slightly bigger in the movies [ref.](http://forums.animesuki.com/showthread.php?p=2111156)

Comment: Just one request for the answer: Can you give a brief description of what was in the added footage for the first movie?

Comment: I couldn't find what was added in the first film, having seen it though it's probably just longer fight scenes or something else nonessential